# Count on joined table causes return of 1 row

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I've got query like:

```
SELECT 
    b.title,
    b.url,
    b.`date`,
    b.gallery,
    count(c.id) as comments_count,
    a.name,
    b.content,
    b.comments,
    LEFT(b.content, LOCATE('&lt;page&gt;', b.content)-1) as content_short 
FROM blog b 
LEFT JOIN blog_comments c ON 
    (b.id = c.note AND c.approved = 1) 
LEFT JOIN administrators a ON 
    (b.aid = a.id) 
WHERE 
    b.`date` < now() AND 
    b.active = 1 
ORDER BY b.`date` DESC;
```

Now, when I remove `count(c.id) as comments_count,`, I've got 2 rows returned. When it's present, there's only 1 row returned.

Is there some way to fix ot or I simply have to change
`count(c.id) as comments_count,` to `(select count(id) as`comments_count`from blog_comments where note = b.id) as comments_count,`?

Comment: And your data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Count(*)` is an aggregated function, so it will apply in a group.
That means that when you count on groups, it will apply the function on every group.
The groups are formed when you use Group By, in this case, you're not using, so `MySQL` consider that ALL select (your joins) is **ONLY 1 GROUP.**

So, applies the count on the unique group and returning the count of rows.

you should add  a `Group by` by the field you want

An example is [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)

Comment: Thorough explanation.  +1.  The manual page on [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) explains it thus: "*If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*"